# Apache HttpClient proper handling of cookies?

Tags: java, apache, cookies

I'm writing an application that can communicate with a website and do things such as login, post stuff, etc.

Long story short, the application is working fine. Although, I'd like to make it more efficient rather than doing a low-level cookie integration.

I'm currently using

```
post.setHeader("Cookie", "abc");
```

I'm well aware of the `CookieStore` method, I've been searching all over Google/Stackoverflow for help. So the issue I'm having is, my cookies are predefined in my code, that's a problem because some of the generic keys in my cookie can expire. The cookies have `cached` or `generic` generated keys, that are given out individually.

I need to be able to go to the website, and store whatever cookie is given to me first. THEN begin executing my code to login. As of right now, the cookies are null.

How would I approach this? I want to be efficient, I was thinking of running a "dummy" execution on the website, and then copy over the given cookies to the low-level cookie storage. (I feel there is a better way, that's why I'm hoping to get some input here)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I used the BasicCookieManager only, and I had it query all the Cookies using List to view whether or not the cookies are active. Works flawlessly.